# How to get the head node in linkedlist python

Tags: python

I've been trying to find a way to get the first data.

this is my data in database for example.

```
id    name     next
001   task1    002
002   task2    003
003   task3    000
```

what I want to do is to get the first value of the headnode which should be `001` as shown in the database.

this is my code

```
while True:
    self.headNode = 000
    try:
        lastNode = Task.objects.get(next=self.headNode)
        self.headNode = lastNode.id
        break
    except Task.DoesNotExist:
        break
```

What I expect here, the value of self.headNode should be `001` but it gave me `003`. Please help me how to get that `001`. I've been working on this for almost a month now.

this is the other data example.

```
id    name     next
222   task1    444
333   task2    222
444   task3    000
```

in here... the head node should be `333` and to know that. i will just get the data where the `next` is `000`. Then get its so it is `444`. then I will get the other data where the next is `444` and the `id` is `222`. lastly get data were `next` is `222` then you will get the id `333`. so that would show that the head node is `333`. I hope I have explained it clearly.

Comment: I think you confused `break` and `continue`. `break` exits the current loop, in this case, the `while True`, so you will enter one and only one time in your loop. `continue` stops the current iteration and starts the next one.

Comment: @Rightleg Ah I see. I have also tried `continue` but it gives me infinite loop.

Comment: The loop only runs once, since you have added a break statement. Also, since the initial value of headNode in 000, lastNode will contain 003 since the query you have written, filters as next=000, which us the id 003. That's why you're getting 003

Comment: Now I get it. thanks @aliasav, could you please suggest how I possibly get this `001`? I've been really stuck here

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the headNode is not any other node's next, is that right?

Comment: @aliasav, yes that is right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop only runs once, since you have added a `break` statement.

Also, since the initial value of headNode in 000, lastNode will contain 003 since the query you have written, filters as next=000, which us the id 003. That's why you're getting 003

Okay, so if the headNode is a node that is not any other node's next, you can retrieve it this way:

```
self.headNode = 000
while True:    
    try:
        lastNode = Task.objects.get(next=self.headNode)
        self.headNode = lastNode.id        
    except Task.DoesNotExist:
        print("Head Node ->", self.headNode)
        break
```

Comment: but the head node is unknown.

Comment: I will just be able to know that it is the head node because it does not have any data which is the same as the value of its `Next`

Comment: Please properly specify how you would identify a head node in your context

Comment: And if your headNode is the first object in the Task model, then you can retrieve it using Task.objects.all()[0] method.

Comment: it is not always the the first object. I will update my question of I could show you other possible Db

Comment: I have already updated my question. Can you please check it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh it works... Thank you so much. I have been trying this for a month now but you have saved my life!!!!